# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget "Not similar to others"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am getting this error while debugging although it is not creating any issue. Still can someone tell problems created by this warning. My code file is very big I can't share it but it is giving map of my widget tree. Can someone please tell me where the error is lying

**Row ← Expanded ← Padding ← DecoratedBox ← Padding ← Container ← Expanded ← Column ← Padding ← Padding ←**

> ```
> The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData. 
> Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
> The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Padding widget.
>
> The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
>   Row ← Expanded ← Padding ← DecoratedBox ← Padding ← Container ← Expanded ← Column ← Padding ← Padding ← ⋯
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
> #0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData.<anonymous closure>
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5626
> #1      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5642
> #2      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5664
> #3      RenderObjectElement.mount
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5357
> #4      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6090
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an expanded widget as the child of a container widget and that is not permitted in Flutter.

An expanded widget should only be direct child of widgets such as Column, Row, ...

Answer (score 2):

`Container ← Expanded ← Column ← Padding ← Padding`

The `Expanded` Widget must be used as a child of a flex, this hierchy shows that Expanded is rendered within a `Container` Widget.